# Apply special price to a list of products

Tags: magento-1.8, product, special-price

I want to apply a percentage special price to a group of products(list of SKUs) without manually going through each of one of them. Is there a way to this in backend or programmatically in magento ?

Answer (score 2):

you could add those products to a category, then create a Catalog Price Rule and in the Conditions tab, set the Category to the category you just created.
[image]

Then in Actions you supply discount amount By Percentage of Original Price
[image]

Comment: what's does priority in rule information means ? because it's set to 0 and after clearing the cache i don't see the rule applied on products of that category.

Comment: you might need to reindex. if you have other rules that affect price, you might want to set Stop Further Rules Processing to Yes, see if that helps