# Apply discount code to certain products

Tags: magento-1.9

Is there a way to apply for a price discount (e.g. 10% off) specific products? Will I have to do this for each product one by one?

Comment: check this answer, sounds like exactly the same problem http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/107589/apply-special-price-to-a-list-of-products/107597

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can apply a price discount for specific products and no you won't have to this for each product one by one.

You will have to use the **Catalog Product Rules** to do so, a complete documentation is available here: http://merch.docs.magento.com/ce/user_guide/marketing/price-rules-catalog.html

Using the conditions you can specify a pool of products on which to apply your discount.

If you need a shopping bag discount using a coupon code then I suggest you look at the **Shopping Cart Rules** : http://merch.docs.magento.com/ce/user_guide/marketing/price-rules-shopping-cart.html